# Auto Number Cells (1,2,3,etc) if the adjacent cell is not blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA Excel and wondering if you can help.

I have tried typing something similar to this `=IF(C10,(ROW(A10)-ROW(A$9)),"")` and it works. However, the downside to this is you have to enter this formula into every cell that you want to auto populate. I am trying to find a macro code in Excel so that cells will auto number 1,2,3,etc. whenever the adjacent column contains data?

For example, when a user enters data into `B1`, `A1` will automatically be populated to 1. Then when users enters data into `B2`, `A2` will automatically be populated to 2 and so on. Then when users delete data from B column, adjacent column in A will not contain a number.

Comment: What's your existing code? Where are the bugs?

Comment: I am new to VBA Excel, I cannot find the answer to this at all anywhere.

Comment: This can be done with a formula. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been using something similar to this =IF(C10,(ROW(A10)-ROW(A$9)),""). But this won't work if you do not know the total rows you need. In addition, you need to enter this formula into all the cells that you want to auto populate. I'm looking for something in the View Code of Sheet 1 that once you enter data in column B, column A will auto number.

Comment: Can't answer since it was downvoted into on-hold status. It doesn't look like any vba is needed here.

A better formula would be =IF(B2<>"",COUNTA($B$2:B2),"")

If your issue is formulas not autocompleting as data is entered, set your range as a data table.

Answer (score 1):

Enter this into `A1` based on what you said:

`=if(isblank(B1),"",row())`

If you want this in VBA you can use the following, but this assumes your data starts at Row 1. If it you want the numbering at Row 2 to start as 1, just add "-1" after the RngA part.

```
Sub Serial()
Dim RngA As Long, LastRow as Long 'Declares the variables used

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'This finds the last row in Column B where the loop will end.

For RngA = 1 To LastRow ' This loops from the first row to the last cell filled in column B
    If Cells(RngA, 2) <> "" Then ' If Column B is blank, skip this row
    Cells(RngA, 1).Value = RngA 'Column B was not blank, so put the row number in column A
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I was looking more towards something in the code behind of Excel. Right-Clicking Sheet1 and select View Code. I have something similar to what you posted =IF(C10,(ROW(A10)-ROW(A$9)),""). However these won't work if you do not know the total cells or rows that you'll need.

Comment: Are you trying to skip numbers or are you trying to serialize them. Meaning say B3 is blank, should A4 say 3 or 4 (assuming everything else is not blank)?

Comment: No, if B3 is blank then A4 and A3 should be blank. For example, if I type data in B1, A1 will auto number to 1. If I type data into B2, A2 will auto number to 2 and so on to infinite if I do enter infinite data into column B. Afterwards if I delete data from the very last row of column B then the cell in column A will no longer have a number.

Comment: Are there cases where let's say B1:B2 have stuff, B3 is blank and B4 had stuff?

Comment: No, every cell within that column will have data. Another example is lets say my starting point of entering data is B21 then A21 will auto populate to be #1. If I enter data into B22, A22 will auto populate to be #2 and so on.

Comment: Will your data always start at the first row or will this vary?

Comment: It will varied. I can change the code around to the starting point but I would like to see an example in how it works in the macro code rather than going the route of having a formula in the cells.

Comment: Ok I adjusted my answer to include a macro that will loop through the cells in Column B until the last filled row in Column B to see if there's a value. If it's blank it will skip otherwise it will basically put the row number. If you want a count, I would use a `COUNTA` from the top to wherever you are in RngA to give the number so it's serialized.

Comment: Mark, can you explain your code? I tried it and nothing happened when I typed something into B1.

Comment: I should clarify that i didn't set this up as a sub that will automatically run. You should run the code to make it work. If you want it to run everytime something changes on your sheet I can do that, but I caution this may slow down the sheet itself.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your time. I don't think I can explain my question properly without actually demonstrating what I mean.